# How to pass secrets when building docker Windows images

Tags: docker

Summary of the question: what is the equivalent of using the docker build --secret option for Windows image/containers, or what to do instead?

I have a number of docker images which support the agents in our Jenkins build system - both Windows and Linux images of various varieties. These are, amongst other things, pre-populated with some of the repos we use. These repos are not public and they need credentials to clone them - the credentials are currently in the form of a username password, if it matters. These images are themselves built by Jenkins - so the username/password pair comes from Jenkins Credentials. I obviously don't want to install the credentials in the history or layers of the images I produce.

I currently use an approach of cloning the repos on the host machine, from which I call "docker build" and then copying them into the image using COPY in the Dockerfile. This works but, at least when called from a build system, docker always thinks the files have changed and never hits the cache. I should say that building the images from the top can take a few hours (we build a lot of third party libraries in the process) and I can only really add these copies right at the end, or we'd get these rebuilds every time. There is a longer story, but I now need to move these earlier and am looking at other ways to avoid the cache miss issue.

For Linux images I have been experimenting with using --secret parameter to pass the password environment parameter I get from Jenkins, and then in the Dockerfile adding a script for GIT_ASKPASS which will cat the contents of the file. This is all secure because the secret only exists for the duration of the docker build execution. So far so good, I believe.

However, the --secret parameter is really just an option of the buildkit (so "docker buildx build") and the buildkit only works for Linux containers. The question is what to others do in this scenario for Windows images/containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one answer to this, but not a direct answer but an alternative approach.

Essentially I continue to use COPY in the Dockerfile but with a key difference: on the host environment, after I clone the repo in question and before calling "docker build" I delete the .git/logs directory. With that change, if there are no additions to the repo then there will a cache hit compared to a previous time. (If you don't delete that directory then if we reclone the repo then there will always be a cache miss, even if the actual repo has not changed).

One extra I've not tried is to use --single-branch on the clone, so we only get the branch I am interested in - otherwise a commit to a different branch would still result in a branch miss.

Worth noting that this solution works differently than calling "git clone" directly in the Dockerfile. Specifically when calling from Dockerfile, "git clone" will never be a cache miss - docker ignores the contents. Whether this is what you want will depend.

Comment: Perhaps you could even make your life easier by making use of a `.dockerignore` file that contains `/.git` or `/.git/logs` - then your git files will never be the cause of a miss with regard to cached docker layers? Though, I guess what I'm assuming is that you won't be doing more git operations from inside this container?

Comment: I actually do further git operations in the image, or at least subsequently in containers, but the suggestion of adding .git/logs to .dockerignore sounds plausible.